# Nested conditional statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

please the code below determines the length of shortest path between two randomly selected nodes, it then prints the length of the path between them. I need to insert a condition within the loop that tests the tests the length of path between the two nodes and continues until all the output meets this condition (>= 1.5 and <= 2). I am really confused as to how I can nest that within the existing loops. I have included what I tried in triple quotes. That seems to be an infinite loop hence not helpful. Please help. Thanks

```
import networkx as nx
import random as rand

pos = {1001:(-42503,-3748871),1002:(-42267,-3749806),1003:(-40938,-3750235),1004: (-39452,-3750624),1005:(-39985,-3749564),1006:(-38473,-3749615),1007:(-41714,-3747171),1008:(-42279,-3745275),1009:(-41853,-3744185),1010:(-42000,-3746561),1011:(-42651,-3746188),1012:(-42195,-3747788),1013:(-41498,-3748890),1014:(-40366,-3748684),1015:(-43036,-3750284)}

edge = [(1001, 1003,{'length':0.35}),(1001, 1004,{'length':0.46}),(1001, 1009,{'length':0.49}),(1002, 1007,{'length':0.22}),(1002, 9972,{'length':0.54}),(1002, 1013,{'length':0.59}),(1003, 1014,{'length':0.25}),(1004, 1010,{'length':0.29}),(1004, 1013,{'length':0.57}),(1004, 1003,{'length':0.43}),(1004, 1006,{'length':0.37}),(1005, 1002,{'length':0.23}),(1005, 14566,{'length':0.72}),(1006, 1005,{'length':0.6}),(1007, 1003,{'length':0.39}),(1007, 1010,{'length':0.11}),(1009, 1001,{'length':0.51}),(1010, 1005,{'length':0.2}),(1011, 1004,{'length':0.37}),(1012, 1006,{'length':0.17}),(1013, 1005,{'length':0.19}),(1013, 1007,{'length':0.21}),(1014, 1005,{'length':0.35}),(1014, 1009,{'length':0.51})]


X = nx.MultiDiGraph()
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
X.add_edges_from(edge)


num_routes = 5

for i in range(num_routes):

while True:

    try:
        A = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
        B = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
        path = nx.dijkstra_path(X,A,B,weight='length')
        pathlength = round(nx.dijkstra_path_length(X,A,B,weight='length'),2)

        ''' 
        while pathlength >= 1.5 and pathlength <= 2: 

            continue

        else: pathlength = round(nx.dijkstra_path_length(X,A,B,weight='length'),2)

        '''

    except:

        continue

    break

print pathlength

output:
pathlength:  2.2
pathlength:  2.94
pathlength:  1.46
pathlength:  1.37
pathlength:  0.77
```

Comment: Do you want to keep trying random points until your condition is met?

Comment: @KSab, yes. keep randomly selecting nodes until the length between the 5 selected node pairs meet the condition. Thank you

Comment: You had to just change your inner while loop to a if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(num_routes):
    while True:
        try:
            A = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
            B = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
            path = nx.dijkstra_path(X,A,B,weight='length')
            pathlength = round(nx.dijkstra_path_length(X,A,B,weight='length'),2)
            print path,A,B,pathlength  ,i
            if 1.5 <= pathlength <= 2:
                break
            else:
                pathlength 
        except:pass
    print pathlength,A,B
```

This should work.  If I understand you correctly that is!
Edited my code, I was doing extra loops needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem a little confused about the functionality of `break` and `continue` in loops. `break` will tell python that it should immediately finish the loop without any more iterations while `continue` just tells it to skip over the rest *current* iteration and move on to the next (basically restarting the loop in the case of `while True:`. The `break` you have at the end of your while loop immediately exit the loop right after the first time it runs!

```
for i in range(num_routes):

    while True:

        try:
            A = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
            B = int(rand.choice(pos.keys()))
            path = nx.dijkstra_path(X,A,B,weight='length')
            pathlength = round(nx.dijkstra_path_length(X,A,B,weight='length'),2)
            if pathlength >= 1.5 and pathlength <= 2: 
                break
        except:
            continue

    print pathlength
```

Comment: if the node is not reachable the exception  "networkx.exception.NetworkXNoPath: node ...not reachable from ..." is thrown.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah okay thanks, I'm not familiar with networkx and have edited accordingly.

Comment: @KSab thanks for helping, it works well now and thanks for the explanation you provided above. As for the except statement, Padraic was right. Thanks again